# d3 v4 function gives TypeError: d3.timeParse is not a function

Tags: d3.js

I loaded d3 v4 but it gives error at line below:
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");
TypeError: d3.timeParse is not a function

Not sure if this happens because I loaded also v3  which is used for another component. But it shouldn't since the message is about not finding the function.

Comment: Are you sure you really are working with d3 v4 at that point ? If you put a breakpoint in your code at that exact line and type 'd3' in the console, what does it output ? You should get something like this : `Object {event: null, version: "4.3.0", symbols: Array[7], symbolCircle: Object, symbolCross: Object…}`. I suspect you are working with the d3 v3 version because the function definitely should work

Comment: @HugoMigneron 's point was my problem. I had accidentally copied a link to v3 out of tutorial while messing around and had not caught it. Loading two versions is bound to cause problems, so you are working in v3.

Answer (score 3):

In d3 you can use:

**v3:**

```
var timeParse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var date = timeParse(_date);
```

**v4:**

```
var timeParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var date = timeParse(_date);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");  "d3.timeParse is not a function"